# Concise proof that $\lvert a-b\rvert < \frac{\lvert b \rvert}{2} \implies \lvert a\rvert > \frac{\lvert b \rvert}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

I am only considering $\mathbb{R}$ in this context. I understand why the statement holds and can prove it geometrically, but I can’t think of a concise way to derive the consequent from the precedent in a purely algebraic way.

Comment: Willingness to get down in the mud is a powerful weapon for math problem solvers.  If no elegant analysis such as the answer of DalatKarelia occurs to you, the problem can certainly be conquered by *Cases*.  Either $b < 0$ or $b \geq 0$.  Either $a < 0$ or $a \geq 0$.  Either $(a-b) < 0$ or $(a-b) \geq 0$.  When examining these $(2^3 = 8)$ cases, certainly you are re-inventing the wheel, re the original theorem of $|a + b| \leq |a| + |b|$, and its subsequent applications.  But, so what?  If the elegant approach doesn't occur to you, get down in the mud.

Comment: @user2661923 I did actually know how to go about it in a 'muddy' way, which is why I insisted on a $concise$ proof in my question. The whole thing was really born out of a brain freeze on my end. But thank you for the advice, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** $|a-b| \ge |b| - |a|$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Ah, the reverse triangle inequality, of course, completely forgot about it. Thank you. Never a good idea to do maths at 3AM I guess!

Comment: @ChubbyChef: Sure. Glad you got it.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $|a-b|\lt\frac12|b|$ and $|a|\le\tfrac12|b|$.

The triangle inequality says that $|b|\le|a-b|+|a|$, but the assumption implies that $|a-b|+|a|\lt|b|$. Thus, the assumption is false.

One negation of the assumption is
$$
|a-b|\lt\frac12|b|\implies|a|\gt\tfrac12|b|
$$